# Why the code of std::tuple can't compile on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

I have a piece of C++ code used std::tuple. I have enabled C++17 standard in both MSVC and g++. But it can only be built by g++.

As follows:

```
#include <future>
#include <utility>
#include <typeindex>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<std::tuple<std::type_index, int>()> task{
        []() {return std::make_tuple(std::type_index(typeid(int)), 3); }
    };
}
```

Error in MSVC:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2512   'std::tuple::tuple': no appropriate default constructor available    TestConsole C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\future  213

I've also tried this, seems like it can't accept a type that don't have any default constructor:

```
#include <future>
#include <utility>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(int a) { a_ = a; }
    int a_;
};

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<std::tuple<Foo, int>()> task{
        []() {return std::make_tuple(Foo(3), 3); }
    };
}
```

I'm wondering what caused the problem and how can I solve it(or is there a better way?).

Any help will be really appreciated.

---

Edit: I've change `int*` into `int`. I don't think `nullptr` or `int*` is the point. It also can't be built. Thanks a lot.

Edit: I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.3.8)

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the type of `nullptr`?

Comment: I think you have xy problem. What do you want from always nullptr?

Comment: What version of VS?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I've edited the post. Thanks a lot for pointing that.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.3.8)

Comment: [std::nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t)

Comment: Works for me in GCC something-or-other (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82db994e3f74b355, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4176ea9a2aa22616). VS bug? They've had [a similar one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108672/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta.html) before

Comment: Looks like the way MSVS implements the code it requires the return type to be default constructable.  See: https://godbolt.org/z/sbzqf.  I'll have to check the standard to see if this is conformant or not.

Comment: I can't find any restrictions on the type so it looks to be a bug.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Seems like your link went wrong(404).

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure what happened there.  Here you are: https://godbolt.org/z/sbzqf-

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks a lot. Maybe I should avoid using std::package_task in MSVC